# Using filters in props with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm wondering how I can use filters whilst passing a prop to a component. I'm using the [Element UI toolkit](http://element.eleme.io/) Here is an example of my basic component:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <el-table
      :data="failures"
      style="width: 100%">
      <el-table-column
        prop="created_at | moment"
        label="Date"
        width="180">
      </el-table-column>
    </el-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import moment from 'moment';
    export default {
      props: ['failures'],
      filters: {
        moment: function (date) {
          return moment(date).fromNow();
        }
      },
      mounted() {

      }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I am trying to use my filter on this prop here:

```
<el-table-column
   prop="created_at | moment"
   label="Date"
   width="180">
</el-table-column>
```

Using `| moment` doesn't seem to work, what other method could I use to apply this filter to the prop?

Thanks

Comment: change `prop` to `:prop`,and where is `created_at`

Answer (score 1):

As elment-ui only use prop value as field name rather than binding it's value, so we cannot use filter directly. I got a way to achieve this by **formatter**, following is code snippet.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-table :data="failures" style="width: 100%">
            <el-table-column :formatter='formatter' label="Date" width="180">
            </el-table-column>
        </el-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['failures'],
    methods: {
        formatter(row) {
            return moment(row.created_at).fromNow()
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're now passing your prop as a string. You should probably use `:prop="created_at | moment"`.

Comment: I don't think so. please take a look at offcial demo over [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)